# Wordpress REST API create custom GET endpoint from custom table

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm trying to get some data from a custom database table. But I get a rest forbidden error.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'emevents/v1', '/all', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'handle_get_all',
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' );
    }
  ) );
} );

function handle_get_all( $data ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT event_name FROM 'wp_em_events'";
    $list = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: No, I have not.